# How do I create a spinner in a fragment layout?

Tags: android, android-fragments, android-spinner

I am following Google's [spinner example](https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/controls/spinner#java) to create a simple `Spinner` in a `Fragment`. Here is what I have done so far:

**fragment_home.xml**

```
<Spinner
    android:id="@+id/spinner"
    android:layout_width="0dp"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_marginTop="6dp"
    app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="@+id/textView5"
    app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="@+id/textView5"
    app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/textView5" />
```

**HomeFragment.java**

```
public View onCreateView(@NonNull LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    ...
    Spinner spinner = (Spinner) getView().findViewById(R.id.spinner);
    ArrayAdapter<CharSequence> adapter = ArrayAdapter.createFromResource(getActivity(), R.array.spinner_options, android.R.layout.simple_spinner_item);
    adapter.setDropDownViewResource(android.R.layout.simple_spinner_dropdown_item);
    spinner.setAdapter(adapter);
}
```

**strings.xml**

```
<resources>
    ...
    <string-array name="spinner_options">
        <item>Round-robin</item>
        <item>Double round-robin</item>
        <item>Swiss</item>
        <item>Knockout</item>
        <item>Team round-robin</item>
        <item>Team Swiss</item>
        <item>Team knockout</item>
        <item>Match</item>
    </string-array>
</resources>
```

When I try to build the app, I get an error:

> ```
> error: incompatible types: HomeFragment cannot be converted to Context
>     ArrayAdapter<CharSequence> adapter = ArrayAdapter.createFromResource(this
>                                                                          ^
> ```

I read in [this post](/questions/45154603/how-can-i-create-a-spinner-within-a-fragment) that I have to pass the Activity as the first parameter instead of the fragment, so I tried replacing `this` with `getActivity()` and then with `this.getActivity()`. In both cases, the app builds successfully but does not run.

Am I doing anything wrong here? Can someone point out my mistake?

Comment: `does not run?` means there is crash report? or it doesn't run with your expectations ?

Comment: The app does not run at all.

Comment: So there must be a crash report or something .. can we have a look on it

Comment: Here it is: `java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{com.example.myapp/com.example.myapp.MainActivity}: java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'android.view.View android.view.View.findViewById(int)' on a null object reference`.

Comment: Does this have anything to do with `getView().findViewById(R.id.spinner)`? Google's example is about creating a spinner in an activity, so they didn't use `getView()`.

Comment: yes that is right .. please check the answer

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are not supposed to use `getView()` in `onCreateView` as the fragment view is not created yet. because actually `onCreateView` returns its view to be created.

So, the below line of code will cause NPE

```
Spinner spinner = (Spinner) getView().findViewById(R.id.spinner);
```

If you want to setup the spinner in `onCreateView` then you need to inflate the view first with

```
 View view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.my_fragment_layout, container, false);
 Spinner spinner = view.findViewById(R.id.spinner);
```

You can use `getView()` for any fragment lifecycle method that comes after `onCreateView` like `onViewCreated`, `onStart`, or `onResume`

Then as you mentioned use `getActivity()` or `requireActivity()` for building up the adapter

```
ArrayAdapter<CharSequence> adapter = ArrayAdapter.createFromResource(requireActivity(), 
                             R.array.spinner_options, 
                             android.R.layout.simple_spinner_item);
```

Comment: Actually the view was already inflated earlier in `onCreateView()`. Thank you, this works.

Comment: @WaisKamal welcome.. for fragment lifecycle methods you can have a look at [here](https://developer.android.com/guide/fragments/lifecycle)